# Multi Object Tracker with YOLOv5

Tags: computer-vision, tracking, yolo

I'm using [YOLOv5](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) to detect multiple object in every frame of a video using a webcam. I would like to track objects instead of detect them every frame and in order to do this I tried [YOLOv5-DeepSort](https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov5_DeepSort_OSNet). There is a big problem though: Yolov5 can be compiled with TensorRT making it quite fast for an embedded board (50FPS) but DeepSort seems like can't be compiled in the same way.

So I'm now looking for an alternative that is not too expensive and that can improve my detection by tracking objects. Any idea? I already tried the KCF tracker from OpenCV and motpy but both are very bad.

Comment: Try CSRT from opencv if the frames are not changing too rapidly

Comment: Updated answer. TensorRT export now supported. Usage example: https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov5_StrongSORT_OSNet/wiki/ReID-multi-framework-model-export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I am the main https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov5_DeepSort_OSNet contributor.

Sadly, there is no TensorRT export option at the moment. You could try using https://github.com/abewley/sort. This is, DeepSORT but without the deep appearance descriptor, so the tracking will only be based on motion, which depending on your use-case could be good enough.

Another option could be to export the models to ONNX which is relatively easy and then load them with TensorRT following some tutorial like: https://learnopencv.com/how-to-convert-a-model-from-pytorch-to-tensorrt-and-speed-up-inference/

**Aug 6 2022 EDIT -------------------**

I added a ReID specific export script to my repo. It generates: `ONNX`, `OpenVINO` and `TFLite` models out of mobilenet and resnet50 `pt` models. I also added a multibackend model loader and inferencer that supports the 3 aforementioned type of models. Planning to add TensorRT in a close future.

A small tutorial can be found [here](https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov5_StrongSORT_OSNet/wiki/ReID-model-export-to-ONNX,-OpenVINO-and-TFLite)

**Sept 9 2022 EDIT -------------------**

TensorRT export and inference now supported. Example usage:

```bash
python3 reid_export.py --weights /datadrive/mikel/Yolov5_StrongSORT_OSNet/weights/osnet_x0_25_msmt17.pt --include onnx engine --dynamic --device 0 --batch-size 30

python3 track.py --source 0 --strong-sort-weights weights/osnet_x0_25_msmt17.engine --imgsz 640 --yolo-weights weights/yolov5m.engine --device 0 --class 0
```

Comment: Hi Mikel, thanks for your work. Currently, I want to track fast moving objects which can be easily detected by yolov5 but strong_sort fails to track it, any reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: You can start by increasing MAX_DIST: https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov5_StrongSORT_OSNet/blob/c0f3a1f453134c1bf5e769cabdc55222d50b6ac6/strong_sort/configs/strong_sort.yaml#L5. This is because the motion uncertainty for high speed object increases and the association area could be too small. Let me know if it works for you @PrakashDahal

Comment: Hi Mikel, I wanted to train custom dataset (visdrone https://github.com/VisDrone/VisDrone-Dataset#task-4-multi-object-tracking) for object tracking. I referred your repository but there finding reid_export.py script gives 404. Would you please consider guiding me for best possible alternative to train model on custom dataset? Thank you in advance.